# Apply filter before query editor steps

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource, powerbi-filters

I have the following scenario. My datasource looks like this:

```
Order Item Type  Value
  1    1    A    14
  1    1    B    10
  1    1    C    12
  1    2    A    12
  2    1    C    19
  2    1    D    15
  2    2    B    11
```

Now I apply a few steps in the query editor, inter alia, a `Group By` (by `Order` and `Item`), so that my finished table looks like this:

```
Order Item  Value
  1    1     36
  1    2     12
  2    1     34
  2    2     11
```

I am looking now for a possiblity to filter my datasource table before the steps are getting applied (Filter datasource > query steps getting applied > chart changes).

In my example here I would filter the datasource by `Type <> B`:

```
Order Item Type  Value
  1    1    A    14
  1    1    C    12
  1    2    A    12
  2    1    C    19
  2    1    D    15
```

And the final table (chart datasource) would be looking like this:

```
Order Item  Value
  1    1     26
  1    2     12
  2    1     34
```

I tried it with parameters. But the problem is I need the filter in power bi online, so that the enduser can apply this filter.

Thanks in advance for any ideas !!

Comment: Is there any reason you apply that filter and aggregation in Power Query? Why not in visualization and measure? If you drop "B" in Power Query, end users can see the value of "B" by no means, because "B" does not exist in the data model.

Comment: Parameter values can be changed in Power BI Online too, if you go to dataset's settings. It isn't very convenient, though

Comment: Yes I need the aggregation for the final data to display. This is just a minimal example as showcase. In reality I cant display the data in the charts without the aggregation because of a few calculated and added columns. And yes I could change the parameter in the datasets settings, but the enduser cant do that.

Comment: It is not very clear to me what you are looking for. Why not load the data as-is, and put a slicer inside the report so that end users can select "A", "B", "C" or any Type?

Comment: There is no `Type` column anymore in the final table (after the applied query editor steps), so I cant put a slicer into the report. The column is getting lost when the grouping is applied.

Answer (score 0):

Don't apply the grouping in your query. Leave the source table as it is, create a measure which sums `Value`, and filter `Type`.

Comment: This doenst work. Like I stated in the comment above, Its a little more complex as this minimal example and I need the grouping. So leaving the grouping is no option.

Comment: Then you need to [edit] your question accordingly, to explain the downstream dependencies of this data. I suspect the answer is to re-engineer your data model...

Comment: My question is fine, this is the only possiblity it can work. If there is no solution, then it cant be done. Yep, re-engineering the data source would be a solution, but I have no influence on that.

Answer (score 0):

using order and item in a table visual(don't summarise) and for value using SUM of values, which can later be filtered by type should give the desired result.

Comment: This doenst work. Like I stated in the comment above, Its a little more complex as this minimal example and I need the grouping. So leaving the grouping is no option.